# How to remove a specific character from array in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I remove a special number from array in this example.
I have 9 numbers in array nums and empty array narr.
I want to delete a random index (let rand) from nums and add this to narr. 
In narr pushing is correct but when i tried delete the same number from nums by pop, splice, slice etc it didn't correct answer. Which metod should i use?

```
function sudoku(arr){
  let nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
  let narr = [];
  for(let i = 0; i<9; i++){
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*nums.length);
    narr.push(nums[rand]);
    nums.pop(nums[rand]);    
  }
  return narr; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `splice()` to remove the element from array. `pop()` removes last element. If you want to remove an element from index `rand` you can use `splice()`

The first argument of `splice()` is the index from which you want to remove element and second argument is no of elements you want to remove

```
nums.splice(rand, 1);
```

Comment: @ArexSpeed Accept the answer if you think it solved your problem. If you have any problem you can ask